# Don't clear textBox.Text After second Process

Tags: c#

I have a problem, After the second Process will the textbox.text cleaned, But how can I set it off.

(don't clean the textbox)

```
        process1.StartInfo.FileName = ("cmd.exe");
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C cscript slmgr.vbs /dli | FINDSTR /i \"Name\"";
        process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process1.Start();
        process1.WaitForExit();
        string sOutput = process1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text = sOutput;
        process1.Close();

        process2.StartInfo.FileName = ("cmd.exe");
        process2.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C cscript slmgr.vbs /dli | FINDSTR /i \"License Status\"";
        process2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process2.Start();
        process2.WaitForExit();
        string sOutput1 = process2.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        textBox1.Text = sOutput1;
        process2.Close();
```

Comment: Did you try removing `textBox1.Text = sOutput1;`?

Comment: I can use textBox1.Text = sOutput + sOutput; but is there a other one way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `textBox1.Text += sOutput1;` for the second process instead.

`+=` will append the text to the end, rather than replacing the text entirely the way `=` will.